# Find duplicates in a array/list of integers

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

Given an `array/list` of `integers`, output the duplicates.

Also, what I am really looking for: what solutions have best time performance? Best space performance? Is it possible to have both best time and best space performance? Just curious. Thank you!

For example: given the list `[4,1,7,9,4,5,2,7,6,5,3,6,7]`, the answer would be `[4,7,6,5]` (the order of the output does not matter).

I wrote up my solution in `python`.

Here's one solution I wrote using a hash and binary search.

```py
def binarySearch(array, number):
    start = 0
    end = len(array)
    mid = (end + start) // 2
    while (end > start):
        mid = start + (end - start) // 2
        if array[mid] == number:
            return (mid, True)
        elif number > array[mid]:
            if start == mid:
                return (mid + 1, False)
                start = mid
            else:
                end = mid

    return (mid, False)

def findDuplicatesWithHash(array):
    duplicatesHash = {}
    duplicates = []
    for number in array:
        try:
            index,found = binarySearch(duplicates, number)
            if duplicatesHash[number] == 0 and not found: 
                duplicates.insert(index, number)
        except KeyError as error:
            duplicatesHash[number] = 0

    duplicatesSorted = sorted(duplicates, key=lambda tup: tup)
    return duplicatesSorted
```

Comment: [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6] - what is the desired output from this input array?

Comment: "Is it possible to have both best time and best space performance?" Good question! Probably no ;)

Comment: @wookie919: [1,4,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the duplicate:

```
l = [4,1,7,9,4,5,2,7,6,5,3,6]
import collections

print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items() if count > 1])
```

Comment: Great solution! Really short and concise. This is slightly faster than the solution I came up with using sorting. However, what is the space complexity of this?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions to finding duplicates. Given this question is completely generic, one can assume that given a list of `n` values, the number of duplicates lie in the range `[0, n/2]`.

What are the possible methods you can think of?

1. **Hash Table approach:**

   Store values while traversing the list if value already doesn't exist in the hash table. If the value, exists, you have a duplicate.

   ```
   Algorithm FindDuplicates(list)
   hash_table <- HashTable()
   duplicates <- List()
   for value in list:
       if value in hash_table:
           duplicates.add(value)
       else:
           hash_table.add(value, true)
   ```

   - Time: `O(n)` to traverse through all values
   - Space: `O(n)` to save all possible values in the hash table.
2. **Sort Array**

   Sort the array and traverse neighbour values.

   ```
   Algorithm FindDuplicates(list)
   list.sort()
   duplicates <- Set()
   for i <- [1, len(list)-1]:
       if list[i] = list[i-1]:
           duplicates.add(list[i])
   ```

   - Time: `O(n.logn) + O(n) = O(n.logn)` to sort and traverse all values
   - Space: `O(1)` as no extra space created to produce duplicates
3. **Check for every value**

   For every value check if the value exists in the array.

   ```
   Algorithm Search(i, list):
       for j <- [0, len(list)-1] - [i]:
           if list[j] = list[i]:
               return true
       return false

   Algorithm FindDuplicates(list)
   duplicates <- Set()
   for i <- [1, len(list)-1]:
       if Search(i, list):
           duplicates.add(list[i])
   ```

   Time: `O(n^2)` number of comparisons are `n*n(-1)`
   Space: `O(1)` as no extra space created to produce duplicates

Note: space for the duplicates array cannot be included in the space complexity equations as that is the result we want.

Can you think of some more?

Comment: The two solutions I came up with are the first two methods you mentioned. Unfortunately, I must have done something wrong with my hash algorithm, as it was performed terribly compared to the sorted array method.

Comment: The results that you might have received for a very small dataset might not be very indicative of the time complexity of your algorithms. Even though one can assume that allocating hash table takes no time, maybe in some environments creating a hash table and storing elements is slower than sorting the array in place.

Try with a much larger dataset like 10K value or a million values and see how your algorithm performs.

Comment: I tried element sizes ranging between 100 elements and 1 million elements. When I used lists with sizes of 10k, 100k, and 1 million elements, I noticed significantly slower performance when compared to the sorted array method.

Comment: You may add the code as an edit to the original post. I'll look into this.

Comment: @OhaiMac I am not sure the code is even supposed to work. Firstly, binary search should be over a sorted array. AFAIU, `duplicates` is not a sorted list.

Furthermore, the idea seems incorrect here. You don't need to search over the duplicates array. Compare this solution with the hash table approach I mentioned above (which is pretty standard), simply add a number to the hash table if it already doesn't exist. Finding a number in the hash table is `O(1)` compared to `O(logn)` for binary search over a sorted array.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding each of your algorithms, but the output is only supposed to list unique integers. That is why my hash algorithm does a binary search in the `duplicates` list to make sure it wasn't already added. And on top of that, when it does not find it, it returns the index to insert at.

Answer (score 1):

Finding duplicates is very similar to sorting. That is, each element needs to be directly or indirectly compared to all other elements to find if there are duplicates. One could modify quicksort to output elements that have an adjacent matching element with O(n) spacial complexity and O(n*log(n)) average time complexity.

Comment: Great points! One solution I came up with used a dictionary and binary search. Unfortunately, that method is not nearly as good as the other method I came up with which is basically what you mentioned above.